# asp:MediaPlayer (Silverlight) Https / http issue

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, cross-domain, mediaelement

we have a site (https://oursite.net) in which we display a videostream hosted on http (http://someserver.com). The site *needs* to be hosted on https, and we don't control the video, so I'm assuming it needs to be on http. we recently added the option to play the stream through the silverlight asp:MediaElement, which works perfectly fine in our test environment (on http) but doesn't work in production (https).

The info on the web is somewhat confusing as I'm having a hard time differentiating between how this stuff worked at different stages in the silverlight development (seems to have been a bit to and fro)

Is this setup possible at all (hosting the player on https but playing a stream on http) with some sort of policy file? 
in that case: does this policy file need to be hosted with the silverlight app (on https) or where the streams are located (http)

Thanks for your time
Andreas

Answer (score 3):

You are running into a cross-scheme violation unfortunately.  The stream would need to match the same scheme (https) as the hosting application.  Unfortunately most streaming isn't available in HTTPS.

Comment: Is there really no way around this? how about the cross site policy files?

Comment: not really -- you mentioned you don't own the video endpoint, so any suggestions on changing that won't help you I'm guessing (i.e., you could put it in an IIS7 web playlist that can be delivered SSL).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the [enableHtmlAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838264(VS.95).aspx) property on the object tag to make sure it is true? Most media players end up using the HTML DOM bridge to communicate with the web page.

It's also likely that there is a cross-scheme issue: you should try and optimize for all assets being on the same scheme (HTTP or HTTPS).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? source says: Sys.UI.Silverlight.Control.createObject('MediaPlayer1_parent', '\u003cobject type="application/x-silverlight" id="MediaPlayer1" style="height:480px;width:600px;">\r\n\t\u003ca href="http://go2.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=114576&amp;v=1.0">\u003cimg src="http://go2.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-width:0;" />\u003c/a>\r\n\u003c/object>');

byt firebug inspect says http://screencast.com/t/ODM4MjE5